# Does Video-React support video Streaming from url

Tags: reactjs, video, video-streaming, video-reactjs

I want to play video from one of the url by streaming in reactjs does this supports [Video-React](https://video-react.js.org/) could someone help me out.

Answer (score 3):

Yes! In their documentation [here](https://video-react.js.org/customize/customize-source/) you can see them creating a source using HLS streaming:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Hls from 'hls.js';

export default class HLSSource extends Component {
  constructor(props, context) {
    super(props, context);
    this.hls = new Hls();
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    // `src` is the property get from this component
    // `video` is the property insert from `Video` component
    // `video` is the html5 video element
    const { src, video } = this.props;
    // load hls video source base on hls.js
    if (Hls.isSupported()) {
      this.hls.loadSource(src);
      this.hls.attachMedia(video);
      this.hls.on(Hls.Events.MANIFEST_PARSED, () => {
        video.play();
      });
    }
  }


  componentWillUnmount() {
    // destroy hls video source
    if (this.hls) {
      this.hls.destroy();
    }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <source
        src={this.props.src}
        type={this.props.type || 'application/x-mpegURL'}
      />
    );
  }
}
```

And use it in your code:

```
import React from 'react';
import { Player } from 'video-react';
import HLSSource from './HLSSource';

export default (props) => {
  // Add customized HLSSource component into video-react Player
  // The Component with `isVideoChild` attribute will be added into video` component
  // Please use this url if you test it from local:
  // http://www.streambox.fr/playlists/x36xhzz/x36xhzz.m3u8
  return (
    <Player>
      <HLSSource
        isVideoChild
        src="//d2zihajmogu5jn.cloudfront.net/bipbop-advanced/bipbop_16x9_variant.m3u8"
      />
    </Player>
  );
};
```

Comment: Thank you @FrankerZ  i will check same if anything else i will getback.

Comment: tried this but get a loading screen loop. even on their demo it loops loading, same with the issue here https://github.com/video-react/video-react/issues/167 and https://codesandbox.io/s/l2k5ql01ol

Comment: you are using the .mp4 format. So forget that and add .m3u8 format videos.(on this URL: https://codesandbox.io/s/l2k5ql01ol?file=/Player.js)